# Objective C - passing parameters to webservice (cakephp) using AFNetworking 2.x library

Tags: php, objective-c, web-services, cakephp, afnetworking

I'm trying to call a webservice method and pass a parameter to it using AFNetworking 2.x. I can access the method (proper route in cakephp is set) but I have a problem with parameters. I'm most certainly missing something here and I will appreciate any suggestions on both server and obj-c side.

iOS side:

```c
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"videoid": @"123", @"vote": @"123", @"udid": @"123"};

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:@"my_url" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The server side:

```php
class APIController extends AppController {

public $uses = array (
    'MobileVote','Video'

);

function vote(){

$this->autoRender = false;
$response = array ();

$param = $this->request->query;
$videoid =  $this->request->query['videoid'];
$voteType =  $this->request->query['vote'];
$udid =  $this->request->query['udid'];

if(empty($udid) || empty($voteType) || empty($videoid) ){

$response['status'] = "err";
$response['msg'] = "missing parameters";
(...)
```

Server response:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: videoid [APP/Controller/APIController.php, line 27]
Notice (8): Undefined index: vote [APP/Controller/APIController.php, line 28]
Notice (8): Undefined index: udid [APP/Controller/APIController.php, line 29]
{"status":"err","msg":"missing parameters"}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective-C, but isn't that a POST request that sends parameters as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It turns out that I have to send GET request instead of POST.

### If you have a problem with API connection I highly suggest to use this or simillar chrome extension - https://www.getpostman.com/